# После transform элемент размытый

Tags: css, css3

Почему буква `C` размытая? Я пытаюсь это адаптировать под разные размеры текста, при `--spanNum: 2rem` можно заметить, что буква  `C` становится размытым

```js
let openSpan = document.querySelectorAll('.openSpan');

for (let i = 0; i < openSpan.length; i++) {
    openSpan[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
        openSpan[i].classList.toggle('active');
    });
}
```

```css
.service-block__card {
 background-color: white;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: -webkit-box;
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-box;
 display: flex;
 -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
 -webkit-box-direction: normal;
     -ms-flex-direction: column;
         -webkit-flex-direction: column;
            -moz-box-orient: vertical;
            -moz-box-direction: normal;
         flex-direction: column;
 max-width: 500px;
 margin: 10px auto 0;
 padding: 10px;
 -webkit-box-align: center;
     -ms-flex-align: center;
         -webkit-align-items: center;
            -moz-box-align: center;
         align-items: center;
 -webkit-transition: all .2s linear;
 -o-transition: all .2s linear;
 -moz-transition: all .2s linear;
 transition: all .2s linear;
}

.service-block__card-text {
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: -webkit-box;
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-box;
 display: flex;
 -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
 -webkit-box-direction: normal;
     -ms-flex-direction: column;
         -webkit-flex-direction: column;
            -moz-box-orient: vertical;
            -moz-box-direction: normal;
         flex-direction: column;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.hide__text {
 overflow: hidden;
 -webkit-transition: all .4s linear;
 -o-transition: all .4s linear;
 -moz-transition: all .4s linear;
 transition: all .4s linear;
}

.service-block__card-open {
 color: black;
 font-weight: bold;
 margin: 10px auto;
 font-size: 20px;
 cursor: pointer;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
     -ms-user-select: none;
         user-select: none;  
 display: block;
}

:root {
 --atf: cubic-bezier(.58,-0.71,.41,1.55);
 --spanNum: 2rem;
 --spanNumTopB: -webkit-calc(-1 * ( var(--spanNum)*1.2 ) );
 --spanNumTopB: -moz-calc(-1 * ( var(--spanNum)*1.2 ) );
 --spanNumTopB: calc(-1 * ( var(--spanNum)*1.2 ) );
 --spanNumLeftB: -webkit-calc( -1 * ( (var(--spanNum)*11)/160 ) );
 --spanNumLeftB: -moz-calc( -1 * ( (var(--spanNum)*11)/160 ) );
 --spanNumLeftB: calc( -1 * ( (var(--spanNum)*11)/160 ) );
 --spanNumSec: 1s;
}

.openSpan {
 display: -webkit-box;
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-box;
 display: flex;
 font-size: var(--spanNum);
 font-family: sans-serif;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
         -moz-perspective: 1000px;
      perspective: 1000px;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
     -ms-user-select: none;
         user-select: none;
 cursor: pointer;
 max-height: var(--spanNum);
}

.openSpan .ab {
 position: relative;
 -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
         -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
      transform-style: preserve-3d;
 -webkit-transition: var(--spanNumSec) var(--atf) transform;
 -o-transition: var(--spanNumSec) var(--atf) transform;
 -moz-transition: var(--spanNumSec) var(--atf) transform;
 transition: var(--spanNumSec) var(--atf) transform;
}

.openSpan .ab > div {
 width: 100%;
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
         -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
      backface-visibility: hidden;
 text-align: end;
}

.openSpan .b {
 margin-top: var(--spanNumTopB);
 margin-left: var(--spanNumLeftB);
 -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg) rotateZ(90deg);
         -moz-transform: rotateX(180deg) rotateZ(90deg);
      transform: rotateX(180deg) rotateZ(90deg);
}

.openSpan .c {
 -webkit-transition: var(--spanNumSec) var(--atf) transform;
 -o-transition: var(--spanNumSec) var(--atf) transform;
 -moz-transition: var(--spanNumSec) var(--atf) transform;
 transition: var(--spanNumSec) var(--atf) transform;
}

.openSpan.active .ab{
 -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg) rotateZ(90deg);
         -moz-transform: rotateX(180deg) rotateZ(90deg);
      transform: rotateX(180deg) rotateZ(90deg);
}

.openSpan.active .c {
 -webkit-transform: rotateX(-360deg);
         -moz-transform: rotateX(-360deg);
      transform: rotateX(-360deg);
}
```

```html
<span class="openSpan">
 <div class="ab">
  <div class="a">Раз</div>
  <div class="b">С</div>
 </div>
 <div class="c">вернуть</div>
</span>
```

Comment: Это из-за работы самого transform, каждый браузер по разному с ним работает и некоторые портят элемент, допустим в FF относительно нормально - [скрин](https://i.imgur.com/2JAseNy.png)

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 я попробовал добавить все возможные префиксы(обновил вопрос), но не всё равно в firefox ничего не получается, не знаете, как там сделать, чтобы слово раз не было видно?

Comment: @Sevastopol' вам было не сложно это записать как переменную, чтобы она относилась ко всему этому в процентах? Я просто не понимаю, как найти эту зависимость

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант, можно использовать `zoom`

PS При зуме видно, что размер шрифта буквы становится чуть меньше. Поэтому можно добавить `font-size`, немного увеличив размер шрифта. Таким образом подогнать его под нужный нам размер и устранить эту неприятность. :)

```js
let openSpan = document.querySelectorAll('.openSpan');

for (let i = 0; i < openSpan.length; i++) {
    openSpan[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
        openSpan[i].classList.toggle('active');
    });
}
```

```css
:root {
 --atf: cubic-bezier(.58,-0.71,.41,1.55);
 --spanNum: 2rem;
 --spanNumTopB: calc(-1 * ( var(--spanNum)*1.2 ) );
 --spanNumLeftB: calc( -1 * ( (var(--spanNum)*11)/160 ) );
 --spanNumSec: 1s;
}

.openSpan {
 display: flex;
 font-size: var(--spanNum);
 font-family: sans-serif;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 perspective: 1000px;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 user-select: none;
 cursor: pointer;
 max-height: var(--spanNum);
}

.openSpan .ab {
 position: relative;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
 transition: var(--spanNumSec) var(--atf) transform;
}

.openSpan .ab > div {
 width: 100%;
 backface-visibility: hidden;
 text-align: end;
}

.openSpan .b {
 margin-top: var(--spanNumTopB);
 margin-left: var(--spanNumLeftB);
 transform: rotateX(180deg) rotateZ(90deg);
  
  zoom: 98%;
  font-size: 2.08rem;
}

.openSpan .c {
 transition: var(--spanNumSec) var(--atf) transform;
}

.openSpan.active .ab{
 transform: rotateX(180deg) rotateZ(90deg);
}

.openSpan.active .c {
 transform: rotateX(-360deg);
}
```

```html
<span class="openSpan">
 <div class="ab">
  <div class="a">Раз</div>
  <div class="b">С</div>
 </div>
 <div class="c">вернуть</div>
</span>
```

Comment: Вот теперь в FF буква **С** размыта - [скрин](https://i.imgur.com/7LX79ls.png)